# Inverse spectrum problem - showing the existence of a 2x2 doubly stochastic matrix,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, inverse-problems

I am working through a couple of problems in Henryk Minc's book, *Nonnegative Matrices*, as a warm-up to understanding the inverse spectrum problem.

This is Exercise 18 of Chapter VII of his book:

Show that for any real number $\lambda_2$ such that $|\lambda_2|\le1$, there exists a $2x2$ doubly stochastic matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda_2$.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

I started with this doubly stochastic matrix and was trying to see whether it could offer some insight:

$$ \large
        \begin{bmatrix}
        {1-\lambda_2} & \lambda_2\\
        \lambda_2 & {1-\lambda_2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks,

Comment: Not quite: what are the eigenvalues of that one?

Comment: Hi Professor Israel, the eigenvalues are $\{1, (1-2\lambda_2) \}$ ... hmm ... should I aim to shift the spectrum to find the desired matrix?  Or, should I try a different approach?  Thanks, @RobertIsrael

Comment: What if you call it $x$ instead of $\lambda_2$?  What should $x$ be to make the second eigenvalue $\lambda_2$?

Comment: Hi Professor Israel, thanks so much -- I was able to solve this problem with your hint.  Have a great night, @RobertIsrael.